# Getting access token using email address and app password from oauth2/token

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm

We are using compulsory two factor authentication for our email addresses under our Active Directory.

I have an app that requires a service account, so we created app password for that service account. We acquire access token using following end point -

`https://login.windows.net/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token`

It works perfectly fine for credentials **without two factor authentication and normal password** but not for accounts with two factor auth and **app password**

If we enter app password it returns this error -

> AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password
>   [image]

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant, which is [in general not recommended](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/) (it doesn't support MFA among other things)
Instead of using that flow, see if the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#daemon-or-server-application-to-web-api) (where you can use an application ID + secret or certificate) fits your needs

In the case of CRM Online, it does support the concept of “[application user](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj191623.aspx#BKMK_ApplicationUser)”. You declare the application in AAD with a secret or a certificate. Then you go to CRM Online and add that “application user” with a custom security role.

[image]

Then you can use code like this to access CRM web services.

```
add-type -path "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
add-type -path "Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll"
$resourceAppIdURI = "https://ORG.crm2.dynamics.com"
$authority = "https://login.windows.net/TENANT.onmicrosoft.com" 
$credential=New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientCredential("b1d83e4e-bc77-4919-8791-5408746265c1","<SECRET>")
$authContext = New-Object "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext" -ArgumentList $authority,$false
$authResult = $authContext.AcquireToken($resourceAppIdURI, $credential)
$sdkService=new-object Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.WebServiceClient.OrganizationWebProxyClient("https://ORG.crm2.dynamics.com/xrmservices/2011/organization.svc/web?SdkClientVersion=8.2",$false)
$sdkService.HeaderToken=$authResult.accesstoken
$OrganizationRequest=new-object Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationRequest
$OrganizationRequest.RequestName="WhoAmI"
$sdkService.Execute($OrganizationRequest)
```

Comment: I can get access token using certificate flow but if I use the access token to consume Dynamics API, it throws 401 unauthorized error.. Why? Back to my old question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39994073/1635060. Dynamics API do not support app-token acquired by client creds.

Comment: I just added info to my original post about CRM Online and the concept of "Application User".

Comment: I am not able to edit Application ID URI.. any reason?

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790170.aspx#bkmk_ManuallyCreateUser, "The User Name, Application ID URI and Azure AD Object ID fields are locked and you cannot set values for these fields."

Comment: One more thing, can I use this access token for webapi (odata) requests?

Comment: I beleive so, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595798.aspx