# Unauthorized error while authenticating Sharepoint REST API using Python

Tags: python, sharepoint, saml, adfs, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to download a file from a SharePoint Online data library via REST API which uses a multi-factor ADFS authentication, so far I found these posts ([Post1](https://allthatjs.com/2012/03/28/remote-authentication-in-sharepoint-online/), [Post2](https://paulryan.com.au/2014/spo-remote-authentication-rest/)) which talk about sending a SAML request to STS to receive a security token from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf, I have found multiple examples online which uses the same method to authenticate their requests. However, when I send the SAML request to the above Microsoft URL, I receive the error below.

> AADSTS50126: Error validating credentials due to invalid username or password.

I have appropriate access to the SharePoint data library as I was able to get a valid response to an API request (to check available lists and not for authentication) when using a browser with authenticated session. Any idea on what I might be doing wrong or even if authentication is possible for MFA secured SharePoint library.

Comment: Did you check my answer? Any follow up question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official word in any Microsoft Documentation to confirm this. But MFA account + AAD token is not compatible.

You have to use a service account (username/password) without MFA enabled for it. This will work when you invoke the SPO web api using the service account for getting tokens.

When you have a browser session in open state, the token will be available in cookies & you will be able to access the library without issue. The same applies to POSTMAN or SOAP-UI testing.

Because MFA needs user interaction, this is not possible. Refer this github issue: [Trouble spo login with an account with multi-factor authentication](https://github.com/pnp/office365-cli/issues/721)

We do "Application User" concept in Dynamics CRM for the same approach. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44132198/7920473)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Arun. I had a feeling that it wasn't possible but needed a third person's review to make sure of it.

Comment: @AkashSingh that’s fine. I remember you put bounty which is expired now.. :)