# Unable to connect to Microsoft Dynamics CRM with PHP and Curl

Tags: php, curl, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to use PHP and CURL to connect to Microsoft Dynamics API so I can read client data from the CRM. The API guide can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt593051.aspx

I've been into the Azure portal and set up a new application, and it gives me the credentials to use (client id, secret, etc.) and the url end points. Using these credentials I am able to successfully connect to the CRM and retrieve a bearer access token, but I am unable to get any further.

When I attempt to use the token to return data I receive the below error message:

> HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied

My assumption would be that I must be passing the token correctly?

My code is below.

```
<?php
// Step 1 - Use the credentials supplied by CRM to get an access token (this bit works okay)
$credentials = array(
    'grant_type'=>'client_credentials',
    'username'=>'xxxxxxxx',
    'password'=>'xxxxxxxx',
    'client_id'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'client_secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxx',
    );
$urlSafeCredentials = http_build_query($credentials);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $urlSafeCredentials);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($response);
curl_close($ch);


// A BEARER access token is successfully returned
$token = $result->access_token;


// Step 2 - Use the access token to request data from the CRM (this bit fails with HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied)

$ch = curl_init('https://clientspecificurl.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/accounts');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Authorization: Bearer '.$token)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($response); // 401 Unauthorized ?!
?>
```

As far as I can tell there is nothing else to configure at the back end, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the parameters to acquire the token, you were mixing the **client credentials flow** and **resource owner password flow** and lack of `resource` parameter.

The client credentials flow requires parameters `grant_type`,`client_id`,`client_secret`,`resource` and the value of `grant_type` is `client_credentials`.

The resource owner password credentials flow requires `grant_type`,`client_id`,`client_secret`,`username`,`password`,`resource` and the value of `grant_type` is `password`.

If you were using the client credentials flow, you can refer [this blog](http://phuocle.net/crm/dynamics-365-online-s2s-authentication-full-explain.aspx) for acquiring the token. And if you were using the **resource owner password**, you can refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454539/using-adal-c-sharp-as-confidential-user-daemon-server-server-to-server-401-u/38008891#38008891).

Details about difference of the flows in Oauth 2 please refer [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a lightweight PHP class for working with Dynamics 365 online Web API. You can find it [here](https://github.com/RobbeR/RDynamics).

BTW in your code you should try "password" inside the grant_type instead of "client_credentials"