# How to integrate Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM Common Data Service using php?

Tags: php, dynamics-crm, common-data-service

I want to integrate Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM Common Data Service using php. I want to perform CRUD of Contact entity using common data service.

**Authentication**
I have only one option to connect with Common Data service using "ClientId or Client Secret based authentication" method. I cannot use any other authentication and authorization method.

I have followed the documentation at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect) but I don't find any sufficient solution.

Microsoft has given a good tutorial at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/php) but I only have client id, client secret and url.

Is there any ***PHP*** library that I can use with client id and secret based authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a day, I got the solution, which is [AlexaCRM](https://github.com/AlexaCRM/dynamics-webapi-toolkit/wiki/Tutorial) library. By using this library, I am able to connect to microsoft dynamics and perform curd opteration as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can find [examples](https://www.example-code.com/phpExt/dynamics_crm_oauth2_token.asp) and libraries online, one example is this [Lightweight connector library](https://github.com/RobbeR/RDynamics). I am not from php background, and I cannot test this myself - so you take it from here.

```
$RDynamics = new RDynamics(array(
    "base_url"              => "https://YOUR_CRM_INSTANCE.crm4.dynamics.com",
    "authEndPoint"          => "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize",
    'tokenEndPoint'         => 'https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token',
    'crmApiEndPoint'        => 'https://YOUR_CRM_INSTANCE.api.crm4.dynamics.com/',
    "clientID"              => "***", 
    "clientSecret"          => "***", 
    'user'                  => '***',
    'pass'                  => '*'
));
```

Update:

Some confusion around different ways of achieving it. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44103941/7920473)

Comment: Seems you don't read the question. For authentication , I only have url, client_id and client_secret. I don't have the credentials that has been used by RDynamics.

Comment: @Saif looks like you didnt read my answer properly. Maybe my first link will answer you. Alexa is referred in multiple php questions in SO if you researched.

Comment: I already go through with your first answer before asking the question on this plateform. And what does it mean by maybe ?